# InputStream freezes UI on Android

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask, inputstream

I am downloading images in background for a list. I have noticed that even with `AsycTask` the scrolling is not smooth. After some hours of debugging, I have came to conclusion that the `InputStream` is the guilty one.

`doInBackground` should be working on a non-ui thread, then why does it impact the UI?
If I comment out the `InputStream` code, the scrolling is smooth.

I have 3 images in a row, so usually 3 images are loaded at the same time.

```
class BitmapWorkerTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Bitmap> {
    final WeakReference<ImageView> imageViewReference;

    public BitmapWorkerTask(ImageView imageView) {
        // Use a WeakReference to ensure the ImageView can be garbage collected
        imageViewReference = new WeakReference<ImageView>(imageView);
    }


    // Decode image in background.
    @Override
    protected Bitmap doInBackground(String... params) {

        InputStream is = null;

         try {
             is = (InputStream) new URL(params[0]).getContent();
         } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
         } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
         }


        return null;

    }


    // Once complete, see if ImageView is still around and set bitmap.
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap bitmap) {
        // REMOVED ON PURPOSE TO CONFIRM THAT INPUTSTREAM IS GUILTY
    }

}
```

Comment: show the calling code pls, this seems to be OK

Comment: I am just creating this object with ImageView for constructor and then calling `executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR, URL)`

Comment: Best way to get a handle on problems like this is with systrace.  See http://developer.android.com/tools/debugging/systrace.html

Comment: @fadden is there much to get a handle on? I already know the problem cause. I just don't understand why?

Comment: i know it is very late. Hope , this will help some one on future. I think you need to open the connection to get the content from the URL. Like, See this Link  http://www.androidhive.info/2012/07/android-loading-image-from-url-http/